# random samples in R

Tags: r, random, simulator, sample

I'm trying to generate 1000 random samples of length 100 from a normal distribution in R.
I feel this should be very straight forward, but I can't get it.

```
for (i in 1:1000) {
  x[i]=rnorm(100, mean=1, sd=1)
}

for (i in 1:1000) {
  y[i]=rnorm(100, mean=1, sd=1)
}
```

But this code tells me that object x is not found (same thing for y)

Any ideas how to fix it?
In the end, I'd like to have two matrices, x and y, where there each column is a random vector

Thanks

Comment: You want `x` to be a matrix or a list maybe? If you want to subset an object, you have to define it beforehand. Plus, `rnorm` is fully vectorized, so no need of a loop. Please specify your desired output.

Comment: I would like to have two matrices, x and y, in which each column of the matrices are random vectors

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a vector of random numbers with as many elements as in the matrix (number of rows x number of columns). Use that to construct the matrix, specifying the number of rows (or columns); the `matrix()` function will infer the number of columns from the length of the vector.

```
> nr = 5; nc = 4; matrix(rnorm(nr * nc, mean = 1), nrow = nr)
           [,1]      [,2]      [,3]        [,4]
[1,]  0.4335546 0.1604642 0.9182186  0.90655887
[2,]  0.5364028 0.9228126 1.2342502 -1.14907299
[3,]  2.3253380 0.9264194 4.4438906 -0.12498029
[4,]  0.4099558 0.7013819 2.3345348  0.03681959
[5,] -0.6206456 2.3659304 1.8343477  0.61415144
```

Comment: Correct answer from Martin.  However since your `rnorm` parameters are not the default m = 0, sd = 1 the term `(rnorm(nr * nc)` should be updated to `(rnorm(nr * nc, m = 1, sd = 1)`

Comment: updated, thanks @SteveM (`sd = 1` is the default; maybe better to be explicit about this as you suggest, but not strictly necessary).